# Change/Define the saving end of a many-to-many relationship

Tags: ember.js, foreign-keys, many-to-many, ember-data, relationship

I've got a many-to-many relationship in my Application between Users and Conversations

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend,
  conversations: DS.hasMany('App.Conversation')    

App.Conversation = DS.Model.extend
  participants: DS.hasMany('App.User')
```

But every time i create and save a conversation, ember tries to save each participant including the ids of their related conversations. But i want the exact opposite of that, i want it to update just that one conversation and send the related participant_ids with it.

Is there a way to make that work?

What i tried so far:

- specifying the inverse key on the user model (`conversations: DS.hasMany('App.Conversation', inverse: 'participants')`)
- the workaround below.

.

```
App.RESTAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend

  serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend
    addHasMany: (hash, record, key, relationship) ->
      type = record.constructor
      name = relationship.key
      serializedHasMany = []

      embeddedType = this.embeddedType(type, name)
      return unless embeddedType is 'always'

      record.get(name).forEach (record) ->
        serializedHasMany.push record.get('id')
      , @

      hash[@singularize(key) + '_ids'] = serializedHasMany

App.RESTAdapter.map 'D4S.Conversation',
  participants:
    embedded: 'always'
```

After that it will save the conversation including the foreign keys but still tries to update the users, so i tried to save it with a custom request and just reset participant sates :/

```
    App.Conversation._createWith = (participants) ->
      conversation = @createRecord()

      participants.forEach (p) ->
        conversation.get('participants').addObject(p)

      # conversation.save()
      adapter = conversation.get('store._adapter')
      adapter.ajax(adapter.buildURL('conversation'), 'POST',
        data: { conversation: conversation.serialize() }
      ).then ->
        conversation.setProperties(arguments[0].conversation)
        conversation.get('stateManager').transitionTo('saved')
        conversation.get('participants').forEach (user) ->
          user.get('stateManager').transitionTo('saved')
        conversation.trigger('didCommit')

      conversation
```

Which finally worked \o/ But throw up the next error :(

Upon loading ember doesn't load the relationship, conversations participants property is always an empty DS.ManyArray

So is there a way to make that work?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Implement your own mapping key, don't use one thats already used.
This implementation solved all my problems:

```
serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend
  ###
  Custom implementation to realize manySaving mapping
  ###
  addHasMany: (hash, record, key, relationship) ->
    @_super(hash, record, key, relationship)
    type = record.constructor
    name = relationship.key
    serializedHasMany = []

    manySaving = this.manySaving(type, name)
    return unless manySaving

    record.get(name).forEach (record) ->
      serializedHasMany.push record.get('id')
    , @

    hash[key] = serializedHasMany

  ###
  Check if manySaving option for a specific relationship is enabeld
  @param {String} type  The record type (usally a model class)
  @param {String} name  The attribute name of the relationship
  @return {Boolean}
  ###
  manySaving: (type, name) ->
    this.mappingOption(type, name, 'manySaving')

D4S.RESTAdapter.map 'D4S.User',
  conversations:
    manySaving: false

D4S.RESTAdapter.map 'D4S.Conversation',
  participants:
    manySaving: true
    key: 'participant_ids'
```